# Solve for $x>0$ the equation $xy''-2y'+\frac{1}{x}y=1.$

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

This is clearly an Euler-Cauchy differential equation, since multiplying by $x$ gives

$$x^2y''-2xy'+y=x \quad \quad \quad(1).$$

The complementary polynomial is $p(m)=m^2-3m+1$ with roots $m_1=\frac{3+\sqrt{5}}{2}$ and $m_2=\frac{3-\sqrt{5}}{2}.$ So the complementary solution is $y_c=Ax^{\frac{3+\sqrt{5}}{2}}+Bx^{\frac{3-\sqrt{5}}{2}}.$ From here I need to use the formula for the particular solution:

$$y_p=-y_1\int\frac{y_2\cdot g(x)}{W(y_1,y_2)}dx+y_2\int\frac{y_1\cdot g(x)}{W(y_1,y_2)}dx.$$

I know that $y_1=x^{\frac{3+\sqrt{5}}{2}},\ y_2=x^{\frac{3-\sqrt{5}}{2}}$ and $g(x)=x/x^2=1/x.$ The Wronskian is

$$W(y_1,y_2)=\begin{vmatrix} y_1 & y_2 \\ y'_1 & y'_2\end{vmatrix}=\begin{vmatrix} x^2 & x \\ 2x & 1\end{vmatrix}=x^2-2x^2=-x^2.$$

So:

$$y_p=-x^2\int\frac{x\cdot \frac{1}{x}}{-x^2}dx+x\int\frac{x^2\cdot \frac{1}{x}}{-x^2}dx=x^2\int\frac{1}{x^2}dx-x\int\frac{1}{x}dx=-x-x\ln{x}.$$

So my general solution should be

$$y(x)=y_c+y_p=Ax^{\frac{3+\sqrt{5}}{2}}+Bx^{\frac{3-\sqrt{5}}{2}}-x\ln{x}-x,$$

but [WolframAlpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=x*y%27%27-2*y%27%2By%2Fx%20%3D%201) begs to differ. Why?

**EDIT:**

Ok now that I got correct roots for the complementary polynomial, this method seems hard to use due to the ugly derivatives of $y_1$ and $y_2$.

Any other suggestions?

Comment: Why doesn't the general solution have any term on $x^{m_1}$ and $x^{m_2}$?

Comment: Please see my edit. I don't think this method is a good one.

Comment: Why don't you differentiate twice your "solution", substitute in the original equation and find out who is right?

Comment: Because wolfram alpha is right. Why would a computer be wrong?

Comment: @Parseval: I added another suggestion

Answer (score 1):

This is a Cauchy-Euler type of ODE. You can use the subsbstitution $x=e^t$, or $t=\ln x\,$, $x>0$. With this change of variables you can reduce your equation to one with constant coefficents. This gives:

$$\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{1}{x}\frac{dy}{dt}$$ and $$\frac{d^2y}{dx^2}=\frac{1}{x^2}\bigg(\frac{d^2y}{dt^2}-\frac{dy}{dt}\bigg).$$

Substituting these into the equation you get the following equation $$y''-3y'+y=e^t,$$

which can be solved by using the method of undetermined coefficients ( to find $y_p(t)$) as well as variation of parameters.

Comment: So, If I find $y_p(t)$, then in order to find $y_p(x)$, do I just need to plug in $t=\ln{x}$ and write out $y_p(t)=y_p(\ln{x})$?

Comment: yes this substittution is valid for the  C-E equations. If you let $y_p=Ae^t$ you easily get $y_p=-e^t=-x$

Answer (score 0):

You had $$y_1=x^{\frac{3+\sqrt{5}}{2}},\ y_2=x^{\frac{3-\sqrt{5}}{2}}$$
 Why did you change your $y_1$ and $y_2$ in your Wronskian?  $$W(y_1,y_2)=\begin{vmatrix} y_1 & y_2 \\ y'_1 & y'_2\end{vmatrix}=\begin{vmatrix} x^2 & x \\ 2x & 1\end{vmatrix}=x^2-2x^2=-x^2.$$

Comment: Because the derivatives of those are daunting. I'm not allowed to bring a computer to my exam who can simplify things for me.

Comment: Derivative of $ x^n$ is $nx^{n-1}$ even if n is not an integer. The only exception is $n=-1$ for which you get $ln(|x|)$.

Comment: What I'm saying is that the determinant gets ugly, and it gets worse when putting the Wronskian inside the integral and simplifying. It would take too long to do in an exam. It's possible, but not practical.